# How to filter a QuerySet to max members of each group in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, web, orm

The model is something like this:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    application_id = models.IntegerField()
    version_id = models.IntegerField()
    # some other attributes
```

where `application_id` and `version_id` together determine an `Application` entry, in that one application may have several versions, and an entry with the largest `version_id` is the application's current version.

And the goal is to find the current versions of all applications. The SQL (in MySQL) is something like:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM application AS app
WHERE version_id = (SELECT max(version_id)
                    FROM application
                    WHERE application_id = app.application_id);
```

How to achieve this?

Please note that the object here is to **filter** the `QuerySet`, rather than only fetching the largest `version_id`, which would be as simple as using a `GROUP BY`, or in django a `values()` followed by an `annotate()`. I'm interested in the other attributes of the current version as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself. `OuterRef` and `SubQuery` are the trick, which are new in Django 1.11, as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, F

def filter_to_current(qs: QuerySet):
    qs = qs.annotate(current=Subquery(qs.filter(application_id=OuterRef('application_id'))
                                          .order_by('-version_id').values('version_id')[:1])) \
            .filter(version_id=F('current'))
```